# Download specific files from subdirectories on a website in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, tidy

I'm having trouble figuring out how to download all of the subdirectories that contain the word extract from this directory :

[http://69.64.83.144/~fl/download/](http://69.64.83.144/%7Efl/download/)

If you take a look each date contains subdirectories. I'd to download the subdirectory that contains the string "Extract" from each of these subdirectories.

I dont really know where to start. Thanks in advance!